# White Spaces Java Text File

Tags: java, file, spaces

Is is possible to remove the white spaces of a `String` in a text file in Java? I have tried my approach but doesn't working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f = new File("ejer2.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    String linea = br.readLine();
    linea.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    while (linea != null) {
        System.out.println(linea);
        linea = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
}
```

The only way I can get the white spaces out of the `String` is when I print the line out in the `While` loop by using the `replaceAll` method in the `String` class, but im trying to take them out of the `String`in the `File`, and I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Comment: @Pshemo I doubt that's the problem. I think he's trying to modify the actual text file, since it doesn't look like his code tries to do anything with the value he reads.

Comment: @Aify Well, `linea.replaceAll("\\s", "");` is not going to work because strings are immutable (`replaceAll` can't affect original string, but instead it returns changed one). Also I didn't post it as answer because like you noticed it wasn't the only problem here.

Comment: @Pshemo I agree with what you're saying, that the code as it was posted wouldn't work anyways, because strings are immutable. Hopefully OP will realize that he has to append the return value to a stringbuilder or otherwise assign it to a String variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to actually replace the spaces in the file, you need to write to the file instead of just reading from it.

You'll need to add a `linea.replaceAll` line inside your while loop.

You'll need to store all these lines as well - I suggest using a Stringbuilder and adding everything you read to the builder (after you run replaceAll).

You'll also need to write the final text to the text file. I suggest using a PrintStream.

eg: `PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("finalFile.txt"));`

then `out.print(yourStringBuilder.toString())`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
   linea = linea.replaceAll("\\s+","")
```

**EDIT:** It is because you didn't save the value of your new string in your variable linea. You have to asign it.

Comment: IM getting the correct output from the console but my original txt still has white spaces.this is my issue is it possible to modify it? From java

Comment: Then you have to print it again in the textfile. With PrinterWriter you will make your buffer connection like this `PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("file.txt");` and then you will have to print on the file, doing this:  `out.println(linea);` Notice that I put `ln` after `print` to print in the next line each time you use it.